# Can Snowflake Translate Integer-notated IP into String IP Address?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake User)

---

Does Snowflake offer a function similar to MySQL's INET_NTOA()?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa

I'd like to translate integer IP notation into strings like:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(167773449);

-> '10.0.5.9'
```

---

Any recommendations?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select BITAND(BITSHIFTRIGHT(ip_value,24),255)::text || '.' 
  || BITAND(BITSHIFTRIGHT(ip_value,16),255)::text || '.' 
  || BITAND(BITSHIFTRIGHT(ip_value,8),255)::text || '.'
  || BITAND(ip_value,255)::text as ip_text
FROM (
  SELECT 167773449 AS ip_value
);
```

given it's just simple bitshifting, the [bitwise expressions](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/expressions-byte-bit.html) are here to help